# thunderbird crash on start-up on Debian in libxul.so after opening /dev/shm

Tags: memory, debian, thunderbird, crash

I am unable to get `Thunderbird` to start-up on my Debian machine.  The `thunderbird` package is from "buster".

I have never tried to get it working before -- this is the first time.  `Firefox` works fine.

Here's what I get when I run it from the command line:

```
$ thunderbird
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 19926
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

If I run thunderbird-bin through `strace`, it crashes right after a file in `/dev/shm` is opened:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/org.chromium.4Awtde", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) =
-1 EACCES (Permission denied)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
```

`/dev/shm` looks fine:

```
$ ls -lsdt /dev/shm/
0 drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 120 May 25 13:40 /dev/shm//
```

`ulimit` outputs:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 200000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30450
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 95
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

When I run it through gdb, it is crashing in libxul:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fbc882e85d1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fbc882e85d1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
#1  0x00007fbc8715879e in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
#2  0x00007fbc871b552c in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
#3  0x00007fbc8744995e in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
#4  0x00007fbc87a87fb7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
#5  0x00007fbc892a3ed2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the same one posted in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=949450 .

The solution is to

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.bin.thunderbird
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird
```

Now, it works fine.

Not sure why the latest fixes to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird` for `1:68.8.0-1~deb10u1` hadn't fixed it.  Obviously, disabling `apparmor` for `thunderbird` is the only fix.